Prove that $h'(t)=\ell'(t).$ How does this proof shows The vector $U$ is independent of the reference time $t_0?$
The velocity of the material point $M$ occupying the position $\vec{x}$ at time $t$ is the
vector $\vec U=\vec U(\vec x, t)=\frac{\partial \Phi(\vec a,t,t_0)}{\partial t}.$
Where $\vec x =\Phi(\vec a,t,t_0)$ defined on the domain $\Omega_0$ and mapped to $\Omega_t.$ Note that $\vec a $ is the position of the material point at time $t_0$ and $\vec x$ at time $t.$
Sure! Here is the LaTeX code with all math expressions using single dollar signs for inline equations and double dollar signs for display equations:
Property 1.1. The vector $U$ is independent of the reference time $t_0$.
Proof: Let $M$ be a particle occupying the positions $\vec{x}$ at time $t$, $\vec{a}$ at $t_0$, and $\vec{a'}$ at $t'_0$ ($t > t_0 > t'_0$). Thus,
$$
\overrightarrow{OM} = \vec{x} = \Phi(\vec{a}, t, t_0) = \Phi(\vec{a'}, t, t'_0),
$$
and
$$
\vec{a} = \Phi(\vec{a'}, t_0, t'_0).
$$
Thus,
$$
\vec{x} = \Phi[\Phi(\vec{a'}, t_0, t'_0), t, t_0] = \Phi(\vec{a'}, t, t'_0),
$$
where $\vec{a'}$, $t_0$, and $t'_0$ are fixed. We set
$$
h(t) = \Phi[\Phi(\vec{a'}, t_0, t'_0), t, t_0],
$$
$$
\ell(t) = \Phi(\vec{a'}, t, t'_0).
$$
Untill here I got from the book Cambridge University Press
0521617235 - Mathematical Modeling in Continuum Mechanics, Second Edition
Roger Temam and Alain Miranville.

Prove that $h'(t)=\ell'(t).$

My attempt:-
$h'(t)=\frac{d \Phi[\Phi(\vec{a'}, t_0, t'_0), t, t_0]}{d t}=\frac{\partial \Phi[\Phi(\vec{a'}, t_0, t'_0), t, t_0]}{\partial \vec a}\frac{d \vec{a}}{dt}+\frac{\partial \Phi[\Phi(\vec{a'}, t_0, t'_0), t, t_0]}{\partial t}\frac{d t}{dt}+\frac{\partial \Phi[\Phi(\vec{a'}, t_0, t'_0), t, t_0]}{\partial t_0}\frac{d t_0}{dt}=\frac{d \Phi[\Phi(\vec{a'}, t_0, t'_0), t, t_0]}{d t}\cdot 1=\frac{\partial \Phi[\Phi(\vec{a'}, t_0, t'_0), t, t_0]}{\partial t}$
($\because \frac{d \vec{a}}{dt}=0=\frac{d t_0}{dt}. \vec{a} $ and $t_0$ are fixed.)
$$
\ell'(t) = \frac{d \Phi(\vec{a'}, t, t'_0)}{d t}=\frac{\partial \Phi(\vec{a'}, t, t'_0)}{\partial \vec a'}\frac{d \vec{a'}}{dt}+\frac{\partial \Phi(\vec{a'}, t, t'_0)}{\partial  t}\frac{d \vec{t}}{dt}+\frac{\partial \Phi(\vec{a'}, t, t'_0)}{\partial \vec t'_0}\frac{d \vec{t'_0}}{dt}=\frac{\partial \Phi(\vec{a'}, t, t'_0)}{\partial  t}.
$$
($\because \frac{d \vec{a'}}{dt}=0=\frac{d t_0'}{dt}. \vec{a'} $ and $t_0'$ are fixed.)
How $h'(t)=\ell'(t).$? How does this proof shows The vector $U$ is independent of the reference time $t_0?$
